# How can I make DataGrid columns stretch as the control changes width?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Right now when i re-size my screen the data grid columns are getting cut. So please give me a solution to re-size my data grid columns when i re-size my window. How can i set a dynamic width to my data grid columns.

```
<DataGrid Name="dtGrid" > 
  <DataGrid.Columns > 
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding custname}" Width="150" /> 
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mobile NO" Binding="{Binding Mobileno}" Width="150" FontFamily="Times New Roman"/> 
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Credit" Binding="{Binding credit}" Width="150" FontFamily="Times New Roman"/> 
     </DataGrid.Columns> 
 </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Post some code that will help in understanding/answering your question.

Comment: here ive given a fixed width of 150 for the column headers... so the width of the datagrid is around 450. Now when i resize the window to less than 450, the datagrid gets cut. So can i give the width dynamically.

Comment: It depends on how you want to display your contents, are you looking for a solution to enable **scroll-bars**  to appear complete content?

Comment: please update the question and don't put the xaml in a comment. Click the edit link of the question.

Comment: No i dont want a scrollbar. Am just trying to make the datagrid responsive. Inorder to make a grid responsive we normally use rowdefinitions and columndefinitions. So is there something similar for a datagrid??????

Comment: For all those who helped.. THANK YOU... i found my solution. i just have to set the width as *. It becomes responsive. :)

Comment: Maybe responsive was the wrong word for what you were trying to achieve. You were looking for auto scaling of the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of giving a hardcode Width to all your columns. You can mention STAR sizing for your columns, so that the columns will auto adjust based on the available size.

```
   <DataGrid Name="dtGrid">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                                Binding="{Binding custname}"
                                Width="*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mobile NO"
                                Binding="{Binding Mobileno}"
                                Width="*"
                                FontFamily="Times New Roman" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Credit"
                                Binding="{Binding credit}"
                                Width="*"
                                FontFamily="Times New Roman" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: If i set the width to star i wont get scrolling for the grid. How do i get scrollbars....